# Foreign key field is not being created in the database

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to associate `Comment` with `User` models, but somehow the field is not being created in the database. When I try to access the page, the following error is shown:

> (1054, "Unknown column 'user_comments.user_id' in 'field list'")

These are in the `models.py`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        ordering = ('date_joined',)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_comments'
        ordering = ('date_created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        content = self.content

        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I name the `user` variable to `user_id`, an error saying `user_id_id` wasn't found will show upon creating a new `Comment` in the admin panel.

** Update **

I dropped the whole database and I removed the `db_table` options, and thus `user_id` has been created. But now, upon creation of a new `Comment`, the following:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/api/comment/add/
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`softwarestore`.`api_comment`, CONSTRAINT `api_comment_user_id_14315666_fk_api_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `api_user` (`id`))')
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Yes I did. Check my comments on the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply replacing following:

```
 user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with

```
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and run makemigrations?

Comment: Yes, just did, and still no difference.

Comment: Can you please run ```python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> ```or delete migrations folder and re-initiate that?

Comment: Odd. Same thing. But when running `makemigrations`, I read "- Add field user to comment".

Comment: I dropped the database, I removed the `db_table` options in `Meta` and changed `User` to `auth.User` and it worked after running everything again, an `user_id` was created. Now, upon saving a new `Comment`, I receive an `IntegrityError` saying a foreign key constraint fails.

Comment: I think you are using ```id``` as well in your serializers. ```id``` is auto incremented while creating new object. Have you put that in your serializer while writing API?

Comment: I figured it out. It has two table for users. The user's being selected when creating a new comment are from `auth_user`, and not `api_user`. (`api` is the name of my application). Is this right? Can I use the `auth_user` table for other regular users or it must be a new table?

Comment: I am confused about this because if I specify the table to be `auth_user` it will say it already exists. How do I use the default `auth_user` table for my `User` model?